# Avoid functions with excessive number of lines

Tags: angularjs

I have an application in AngularJS and I am using Kiuwan to see the quality of the code, I have this error and specifically in the definition of the Controllers ... of course there are many parameters but how can I reduce this?

```
var HomeCtrl = function($scope, $ionicViewSwitcher, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $rootScope, $interval, $state, CONFIG, MESSAGES) {
```

Comment: `this error`: which one ? You could use $injector to fetch the services inside the controller, but it would be a waste of code.

Comment: In fact if I occupy $ inject, in reality, gulp takes care of that, but claims me for the excess of parameters within the function

Comment: Can you show us an error message, please?

Comment: The error is the title of my question and it is of high priority, according to Kiuwan,

Comment: It's a code analysis tool, not an actual error that needs to be fixed. If your situation requires that you inject all of those into your controller there's really no way to avoid it. It's just the nature of the beast. If you're really worried about it perhaps see if you can create some services to handle common functionality so you don't have to inject everything into every single controller.